# How to replace spaces inside a selection

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I have this text :

> He's a **self made man** who gets what he wants.
>
> The small blue **forget me not** flower was first used by the Grand
>   Lodge.

And this function:

```
function MyFunction()
let myList1 = ["self made man", "gorget me not"]
for elem in MyList1
        if search("=/elem", 'W') == 0
           echo "I want to replace space by hyphen between this three words"  
           ---> CODE
        endif
endfor
endfunction
```

I want to get this text after executing the function :

> He's a **self-made-man** who gets what he wants.
>
> The small blue **forget-me-not** flower was first used by the Grand
>   Lodge.

Can you help me to write the missing line (`---> CODE`) ?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `substitute()` function...

```
substitute({expr}, {pat}, {sub}, {flags})
```

- `expr` is the string to work on
- `pat` is the pattern similar to `:s/pat/sub/g`.
- `sub` is the substitution similar to `sub` in the same `:s` command.
- `flags`, should include "g" as in global (again, like `:s`)

So...

```
let elem = substitute(elem, ' ', '-', 'g')
```

The second param could also be `'\s'` indicating a single whitespace char.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my function (based on [@BLayer’s answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23280/10604):

> He's a **self made man** who gets what he wants. The small blue
>   **forget me not** flower was first used by the Grand Lodge.

```
function MyFunction()
     let myList1 = ["self made man", "forget me not"]
     for elem1 in myList1
        if search("=/elem1", 'W') == 0
           let elem2 = substitute(elem1, ' ', '-', 'g')
           exe '%s/'elem1.'/'elem2
        endif
     endfor
endfunction
```

> He's a **self-made-man** who gets what he wants. The small blue
>   **forget-me-not** flower was first used by the Grand Lodge.

Comment: If you want to say thanks, an upvote is a good start! You should accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks DBK. Arsene you're relatively new here so this would be worth reading: https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. I notice for the four questions you've asked that have received responses you haven't accepted (nor, perhaps, voted) on any of the answers. It's a good idea to say "thanks" (with votes/accepts) to people that have taken time out of their day to help you. Cheers. (Oh, also, it's not necessary/advisable to add an answer that basically is another answer plugged into your code.)